# Pilas con arreglos en c++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, array, pilas

Necesito hacer un código que cumpla con estas condiciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya hice el programa utilizando listas enlazadas:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct nodo{
    int dato;
    nodo *sig=NULL;
};

void apilar(nodo *&inicio,int x);
void desapilar(nodo *&inicio,int x);
void mostrar(nodo *&inicio);
void menu();
int pedirop();

int main(){
    int op,n;
    nodo *lista=NULL;
    do{
        menu();
        op=pedirop();
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                cout<<"\n\t->Ingrese dato a apilar: ";
                cin>>n;
                apilar(lista,n);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"\n\t->Ingrese dato a desapilar: ";
                cin>>n;
                desapilar(lista,n);
                break;
            case 3:
                mostrar(lista);
                break;

            case 4:
                cout<<"\n\t->Chau Papuh!!! XD";
          }

        }while(op!=4);

        return 0;
}

int pedirop(){
    int opcion;
    do{
        cout<<"\n\t--->Digite opcion (1-4): ";
        cin>>opcion;
        if(opcion<1||opcion>4)
            cout<<"\t--->Error reingrese!!!";
    }while(opcion<1||opcion>4);
    return opcion;
}

void menu(){
    cout<<"\n\t*************MENU****************";
    cout<<"\n\t1-> Apilar ";
    cout<<"\n\t2-> Desapilar ";
    cout<<"\n\t3-> Mostrar ";
    cout<<"\n\t4-> Exit ";
}

void apilar(nodo *&inicio,int x){
    nodo *nuevo = new nodo;
    nuevo->dato = x;
    nuevo->sig = inicio;
    inicio = nuevo;
}

void desapilar(nodo *&inicio,int x){
    nodo *a=NULL,*p=inicio;
    if(p!=NULL){
        while(p->dato!=x && p->sig!=NULL){
            a=p;
            p=p->sig;
        }
        if(p->dato==x){
            if(a==NULL)
                inicio=p->sig;
            else
                a->sig=p->sig;
            p->sig=NULL;
            delete p;
            cout<<"Se elimino el dato "<<x<<"\n";
            p=NULL; 
        }
        else
            cout<<"No se encontro el dato "<<x<<"\n";
    }
    else
        cout<<"Pila vacía"<<endl;
}

void mostrar(nodo *&inicio){
    cout<<"\nLISTA: ";
    nodo *p = inicio;
    if(p!=NULL){
        while(p!=NULL){
            cout<<p->dato<<" -> ";
            p = p->sig;
        }
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Pila vacía"<<endl;
}
```

¡Pero no sé cómo hacerlo con arreglos!

Comment: Una duda por que se usa el "*" nodo *sig=NULL; y por que aqui "*&" void apilar(nodo *&inicio,int x);

Answer (score 4):

> ¡No sé cómo hacerlo con arreglos!

Usa (obviamente) un arreglo, y un índice apuntando a la primera posición libre.

#### Propuesta.

Cuando apiles, guarda el dato en la posición libre y avanza dicha posición.

```
int datos[0xff]{};
int posicon_libre{};

void apilar(int dato)
{
    if (posicion_libre < 0xff)
    {
        datos[posicion_libre] = dato;
        std::cout << "Apilado " << dato << " en posicion " << posicion_libre << '\n';
        ++posición_libre;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Pila llena.\n";
    }
}
```

Cuando desapiles haz lo opuesto:

```
int datos[0xff]{};
int posicon_libre{};

void desapilar()
{
    if (posicion_libre >= 1)
    {
        datos[posicion_libre] = 0;
        std::cout << "Desapilado dato en posicion " << posicion_libre << '\n';
        --posición_libre;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Pila vacia.\n";
    }
}
```

Para mostrar, imprime los elementos desde el valor anterior a `posición_libre` hasta el elemento en la posición `0`:

```
int datos[0xff]{};
int posicon_libre{};

void mostrar()
{
    for (int posicion = posicon_libre - 1; posicion != -1; --posicion)
    {
        std::cout << datos[posicion] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Planeaba rehacer tu codigo adaptado para el uso de arreglos, pero sinceramente me esta abarcando bastante tiempo, y lo esencial que necesitas tener de conocimiento es siempre que los arreglos son estaticos, es decir, que si o si los programadores nos encargamos de asignarle ya una capacidad maxima de elementos que pueda almacenar, ejemplo:

```
const int DF = 100; //Por costumbre se pone DF que seria la Dimension Fisica
int listado[ DF ]; //Se inicializa un arreglo con la cantidad de espacios especificada por la DF
int DL = 0; // DL = Dimension Logica, seria los espacios que vos realmente tenes ocupado del arreglo.
```

Esta seria la inicializacion basica, cada vez que agregues o elimines elementos de arreglo se debe modificar tambien la DL y ademas, la dimension logica nunca debera sobre pasar a la dimension fisica, ya que estarias agregando elementos en cualquier lugar de la memoria que podria estar o no usando el programa para otras cosa ( stack overflow). 
Esas serian las principales cosas a recordar al momento de usar arreglos. Saludos y espero te sirva.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por responder.